# Automatically putting closing curly braces in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Is there a way to automatically put a closing curly brace as soon as i type an opening curly brace in Visual Studio 2010?

Netbeans offers a similar functionality and it comes in quite handy.

Answer (score 4):

The [Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef/) extension has an option for automatic brace completion.