# Autocomplete blocks in C#

Tags: c#

Iam used to Eclipse and Java development, but because of my job I need to start coding in C#. I find it a bit annoying that visual studio doesn't autocomplete my blocks. For instance when I write a new function, class or statement am used to that the IDE autocompletes my blocks. So when I type:

```
private function sendData(String msg, String email) {
```

and hit `enter` the closing bracket appears automatically, is there any settings that enables this function in `Microsoft visual C# 2010 express` ?

Comment: Funny I come from a c#.net background and actually found eclipse to be annoying with autocomplete parentheses.

Comment: @PaulG Your preferences being the opposite doesn't really help anyone does it.

Comment: @PaulG: We mortals find change hard, don't we.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7401614/automatically-putting-closing-curly-braces-in-visual-studio-2010 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448186/matching-a-closing-brace-in-visual-studio http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1587470/how-to-prevent-auto-closing-of-curly-braces-in-resharper

Comment: Visual Studio and C# make Eclipse and Java look like caveman tools.

Comment: @PaulG I loathe autocomplete (), {}, etc - with you there buddy (+1) Of course, intellisense is from the gods.

Comment: @Inerdial - No I guess this doesn't help, this is why it's posted as a comment and not an answer

Comment: @PaulG good point(+1) and (+1) for your first comment, not a big fan of auto complete either and payo intellisense IS from the gods

Comment: @PaulG I'd still prefer SO comments to be requests for clarification or something else constructive, and not trolling. There's the whole rest of the internet to have pointless language/IDE/brace style arguments on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm almost certain that the Productivity Power Tools extension will give you this feature.  You can find it here:

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef

It's really a great add-on and it will give you a lot more control over options like this.

Answer (score 4):

**This isn't possible with Express versions**, since you can't install extensions. You'll need to use **Professional or higher and use third party extensions**. Some simple free ones will do this (such as [Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef)), as does the commercial product [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/), which does much more more. The later likely would make Visual Studio have other features that you're probably used to comming form Eclipse, such as more refactoring support.

Comment: Just want to make a shout out that I hate ReSharper -- it's not a good fit for everyone.

Answer (score 1):

There is no functionality like this already built-in in Visual Studio, but you can install a plugin like [Brace Completer](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0e33cb22-d4ac-4f5a-902f-aff5177cc94d/) to add the functionality .

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do it by default in Visual Studio. Visit [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com) to submit a feature request.