# VS automatically adds brackets if you press "Tab" after an "else". How can I get it to do that after ANY code block opener?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I just noticed this today and it is amazing! I hate typing out the brackets. But why does this only work for 'else' statements? I want this after `namespace`, `class`, `struct`, `enum`, `for`, `foreach`, `while`, `switch`, `do`, and method headers.

Is there any way to turn this functionality on with a wider scope?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Autocomplete blocks in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10454599/autocomplete-blocks-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

For some of them you hit tab twice to auto complete the block.

Answer (score 0):

try Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > IntelliSense.

You can use the spacebar to select whatever is highlighted in the IntelliSense popup.

OR

You can just type the next character you would type AFTER having normally finished typing.

For example.

I want to enter:
console.writeline
I just type con.wr(" and the rest auto-fills with the correct spacing.
It gets "Smarter" the more you use it.

Type the word "prop" then hit TAB twice.  Watch what happens.  Then you can hit tab to switch between the parameters.

Here is a Youtube tutorial on using IntelliSense, there might be more resources in there for you.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k6Q0NR2Z0nc